# Concatenate multiple files with Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, concatenation

I use below two commands to concatenate multiple files from different directories:

1. Method 1

   type "C:\folder1\file1.txt" "C:\folder2\file2.txt" > output.txt
2. Method 2

   copy "C:\folder1\file1.txt"+"C:\folder2\file2.txt" output.txt

However, the output file in Method 1 contains EOF at the end of every single file. How to get rid of the EOF?

Comment: What if you execute type c:\folder1\file1.txt > output.txt & type c:\folder2\file2.txt >> output.txt  ?

Comment: @MarkAllen it works. it doesn't have EOF in the middle of the output file

Comment: @Sun I'm using windows

Comment: @Sun Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Concatenate Multiple files into One File
Create Test Files**

```
E:\Work\>for %x in (1 2 3 4) do echo %x > %x.txt

        E:\Work\>echo 1   1>1.txt

        E:\Work\>echo 2   1>2.txt

        E:\Work\>echo 3   1>3.txt

        E:\Work\>echo 4   1>4.txt
```

**Verify test file creation**

```
E:\Work\>dir *.txt

        Directory of E:\Work\

        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 1.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 2.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 3.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 4.txt
```

**Concatenate files**

```
E:\Work\>copy /b ?.txt concatenation.txt

        1.txt
        2.txt
        3.txt
        4.txt
                1 file(s) copied.
```

**Verify concatenated file creation**

```
E:\Work\>dir *.txt

        Directory of E:\Work\

        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 1.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 2.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 3.txt
        2017-04-26  02:53 PM                 5 4.txt
        2017-04-26  02:54 PM                20 concatenation.txt
```

**Verify correct contents of concatenated files**

```
E:\Work\>type concatenation.txt

        1
        2
        3
        4
```

Comment: Works for me: `copy /b *.txt concatenation.txt`

Answer (score 1):

For me it is the method 2 with `COPY` that causes the EOF to be added, not the `TYPE` way. You can tell `COPY` to copy the files as binary with the `/B` flag. Then the output will be exactly the files and nothing more.

Comment: It's strange. I'm on win8.1. COPY doesn't include any EOF in the middle of the output file.